# Is it possible to simulate intersecting 'droppables' in jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Say I have a draggable with width 2x that needs to be dropped on an area with width 3x, either at the leftmost or rightmost end (leaving a gap of x on the other side). So for instance I have a draggable div that is being dropped on a tr with three child tds, and can either be dropped simultaneously on the 1st and 2nd td, or 2nd and 3rd td. Can anybody think of a way to achieve this effect with some sort of trickery on top on jQuery UI or will I need to work at a lower level? User feedback is important here - hovering over the 1st and 2nd tds should be conveyed to the user in some way that appears different to hovering over the 2nd and 3rd tds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only have 3 cells, this problem is quite easy to solve. You can simply make the far-left and far-right cells be the droppable elements. Now, when a draggable hovers over one of these to cells, you can change the background color of it and the middle one to a different color.

So, for instance, if your HTML is:

```
<div id="draggable_thing"><!-- who knows... (probably you...) --></div>
<tr>
    <td class="left"></td>
    <td class="mid"></td>
    <td class="right"></td>
</tr>
```

Then you can just do something like:

```
$(function() {
    $("#draggable_thing").draggable();
    $(".right").droppable({
        over: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).toggleClass('over-right-cell');
            $(this).parent().find('.mid').toggleClass('over-right-cell');
        }
        out: function(event,ui) {
           $(this).toggleClass('over-right-cell');
           $(this).parent().find('.mid').toggleClass('over-right-cell'); 
        }
    });
    $(".left").droppable({
        over: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).toggleClass('over-left-cell');
            $(this).parent().find('.mid').toggleClass('over-left-cell');
        }
        out: function(event,ui) {
           $(this).toggleClass('over-left-cell');
           $(this).parent().find('.mid').toggleClass('over-left-cell'); 
        }
    });
});
```

And then all you'll need is a couple different CSS classes to let the user know the action is different. Something ugly like this would suffice for demo purposes:

```
.over-right-cell { background-color: blue; }
.over-left-cell  { background-color: green; }
```

Good luck!

Comment: Interesting approach. My only concern is that the middle cell will have no interactivity, but I can fix this by using the start method of the draggable to insert two equal-width divs into the middle cell, which I can make droppable. Thanks for your help.